# Comparing dates in PHP. Why this code returns true?

Tags: php, date, datetime, compare

I'm trying to compare a future date against today's date. This code should return false but it returns true.

```
return (date('d-m-y') > date('15-03-14')) ? true : false;
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't need the shortcircuit if-else statement, just use

```
return date('d-m-y') > date('15-03-14');
```

Second you're comparing two strings and not two dates so string comparison isn't the same of date comparison.

You should use [`strtotime()`](https://www.php.net/strtotime) function or use [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object

```
return (strtotime(date('d-m-y')) > strtotime(date('15-03-14'))
```

or

```
return new DateTime() > new DateTime('2014-03-15');
```

Answer (score 0):

Because they are compared as **string** not date.

If you want to compare as date, use below:

```
return new DateTime() > new DateTime('2014-03-15');
```

Comment: Thanks.. And it should work with the format d-m-y with no issues right?

Answer (score 0):

date function return string, so you compare two strings:

```
'27-02-14' > '15-03-14'
```

string is compared char by char, at position 0 we have:

```
'2' > '1' - and this is true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the date to an integer using `strtotime()`

```
return (strtotime(date('d-m-y')) > strtotime(date('15-03-14'))) ? true : false;
```

Alternatively use [`DateTime::diff()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)